# Kubernetes can't pull images from docker hub repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Hello Guys hope you well!

I need the that my master machine order the slave to pull the image from my docker hub repo and I get the error below, It doesn't let the slave pull from the repo, but when I go to the slave, manually pull he pulls

This from kubernetes master:

The first lines are a describe from pod my-app-6c99bd7b9c-dqd6l which is running now because I pulled manually the image from the docker hub, but I want Kubernetes to do it.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                            From                           Message
  ----     ------          ----                           ----                           -------
  Normal   Scheduled       <unknown>                      default-scheduler              Successfully assigned default/my-app2-74969ddd4f-l6d6l to kubeslave.machine.pt
  Normal   SandboxChanged  <invalid>                      kubelet, kubeslave.machine.pt  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  Failed          <invalid> (x3 over <invalid>)  kubelet, kubeslave.machine.pt  Failed to pull image "bedjase/repository/my-java-app:my-java-app": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for bedjase/repository/my-java-app, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
  Warning  Failed          <invalid> (x3 over <invalid>)  kubelet, kubeslave.machine.pt  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff         <invalid> (x7 over <invalid>)  kubelet, kubeslave.machine.pt  Back-off pulling image "bedjase/repository/my-java-app:my-java-app"
  Warning  Failed          <invalid> (x7 over <invalid>)  kubelet, kubeslave.machine.pt  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling         <invalid> (x4 over <invalid>)  kubelet, kubeslave.machine.pt  Pulling image "bedjase/repository/my-java-app:my-java-app"
[root@kubernetes ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-6c99bd7b9c-dqd6l    1/1     Running            0          14m
my-app2-74969ddd4f-l6d6l   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          2m20s
nginx-86c57db685-bxkpl     1/1     Running            0          8h
```

This from slave:

```
[root@kubeslave docker]# docker pull bedjase/repository:my-java-app
my-java-app: Pulling from bedjase/repository
50e431f79093: Already exists
dd8c6d374ea5: Already exists
c85513200d84: Already exists
55769680e827: Already exists
e27ce2095ec2: Already exists
5943eea6cb7c: Already exists
3ed8ceae72a6: Already exists
7ba151cdc926: Already exists
Digest: sha256:c765d09bdda42a4ab682b00f572fdfc4bbcec0b297e9f7716b3e3dbd756ba4f8
Status: Downloaded newer image for bedjase/repository:my-java-app
docker.io/bedjase/repository:my-java-app
```

I already made the login in both master and slave to docker hub repo and succeed.
Both have /etc/hosts ok, also nodes are connected and ready:

```
[root@kubernetes ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                    STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kubernetes.machine.pt   Ready    master   26h   v1.17.4
kubeslave.machine.pt    Ready    <none>   26h   v1.17.4
```

Am I missing some point here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull image from dockerhub in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032812/how-to-pull-image-from-dockerhub-in-kubernetes)

Comment: The Kubernetes documentation also has a long section on [Using a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry) which would cover the Docker Hub private image case; have you configured ImagePullSecrets or the kubelet correctly?

Comment: I don't know for sure, also I don't know what put in here --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER, I only created a repository on docker hub with a user a pass and email. Probably is this piece missing on my project. 
@David Maze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For private images you must create a `secret` with `username` and `password` of Docker Hub to Kubernetes be able to pull the image.

The command bellow create a secret name `regcred` with your Docker Hub credentials, replace the fields `<<your-name>>`, `<your-password>` and `<your-email>`:

```sh
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-password> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

After that you need to add in your pod/deployment spec that you want to use this credentials to pull your private image adding the `imagePullSecrets` with the credentials created above, see this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

**References:**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers,

1) Create a secret with the following command:
 [Create a secret for pulling docker images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-by-providing-credentials-on-the-command-line)

2) Create your pod that uses this secret as described here:
[use the secret in pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret)

Answer (score 0):

A detailed script to create the secret and another script to patch all the service accounts can be found in my answer here:

[How to pull image from dockerhub in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032812/how-to-pull-image-from-dockerhub-in-kubernetes/70684974#70684974)

Patching all the service accounts will allow all your k8s namespaces to pull any image from dockerhub without changing the k8s deploy manifests.