# pull access denied for gcr.io

Tags: docker, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, docker-registry

I'm trying to pull an image like this in my project repository and I keep getting this error.

I don't have problems with authentification and **docker login** works fine.

> $ docker pull gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[TAG]
>
> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for
>   gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[TAG], repository does not exist or may
>   require 'docker login': denied: Permission denied for "0.2.0" from
>   request "/v2/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]/manifests/[TAG]".

Any ideas?

Comment: By any chance are you using a private cluster? If so, there are some limitations about [pulling images](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#docker_hub) from public Docker hub. Another similar kind of [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847252/kubernetes-cant-pull-images-from-docker-hub-repository) which will be helpful.

Comment: @Alexandre Can you please be more specific about what commands should I execute?

Comment: Are you using both private clusters and trying to pull images from a public Docker hub? If yes, then it should be [the document](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-dockerhub-mirroring) where you will find those commands. You can also look at [this document](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/) for further assistance.

Comment: Which Docker version are you using? Does this error show up on every pull or just on gcr.io?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure your docker credential with your own credential by executing [this command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/configure-docker)

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

Comment: It shows this: 

`WARNING: Your config file at [...] contains these credential helper entries:
{
  "credHelpers": {
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud", 
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud", 
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud", 
    "gcr.io": "gcloud", 
   ...
  }
}
Adding credentials for all GCR repositories.
WARNING: A long list of credential helpers may cause delays running 'docker build'. We recommend passing the registry name to configure only the registry you are using.
gcloud credential helpers already registered correctly.`


But I still have the same error while pulling